# SVD and singular / non-singular matrices

Tags: node.js, matrix, svd

I need to use the SVD form of a matrix to extract concepts from a series of documents. My matrix is of the form `A = [d1, d2, d3 ... dN]` where `di` is a binary vector of `M` components. Then the svd decomposition gives me `svd(A) = U x S x V'` with `S` containing the singular values.

I use [SVDLIBC](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/) to do the processing in nodejs (using a small module I wrote to use it). It seemed to work all well, but I noticed something quite weird in the running time behavior depending on the state of my matrix (where N, M are growing, but already above 1000 for each).
First, I didn't consider extracting the same document vectors, but now after some tests, it looks like adding a document twice sometimes speeds the processing extraordinarily.

1. Do I have to make sure that each of the columns of A are pairwise-independent? Are they required to be all linearly independent? (I thought nope, since SVD just seems to be performing its job well even with some columns being exactly the same, it will simply show in the resulting decomposition which columns / rows are useless by having 0 components in `U` or `V`)
2. Now that it sometimes takes way too much time to compute the SVD of my big matrix, I was trying to reduce its size by removing the same columns, but I found out that actually adding dummy same vectors can make it way faster. Is that normal? What's happening?

Logically, I'd say that I want my matrix to contain as much information as possible, and thus

- [A] Remove all same columns, and in the best case, maybe
- [B] Remove linearly dependent columns.

Doing [A] seems pretty simple and not computationally too expensive, I could hash my vectors at construction to check what are the possibly same vectors, and then spend time to check these, but are there good computation techniques for [A] and [B]?
(I'd appreciate for [A] to not have to check equality of a new vector with the whole past vectors the brute-force way, and as for [B], I don't know any good way to check it / do it).

**Added related question**: about my second question, why would SVD's running time behavior change so massively by just adding one similar column? Is that a normal possible behavior, or does it mean I should look for a bug in SVDLIBC?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say where the problem is without samples of fast and slow input matrices.  But, since one of the primary uses of the SVD is to provide a rotation that eliminates covariance, redundant (or the same) columns should not cause problems.

To answer your question about if the slow behavior being a bug in the library you're using, I'd suggest trying to retrieve the SVD of the same matrix using another tool.  For example, in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), retrieve an SVD of your matrix to compare runtimes:

```
[U, S, V] = svd(A)
```